# Mongoose Sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with displaying data with sorting. Here is my query,

```
Activity.find({"user_id": sesUser._id}, {}, {offset: 0, limit : 5, sort:{createdAt:1}}, function (e,a){
    ...
  });
```

I have data about 252 length, and my latest data is 9 June 2015. If i use this query i only get data from 5 June 2015/ last week data and not get the latest data, but if i not using sorting, the latest data is appear.

I have used this query below but turns out the result is same.

```
Activity.find({"user_id" : sesUser._id}).sort("createdAt").exec(function(err,a){
    ...
  });
```

Any help? I'm using Mongoose v3

-- edited --
This is my Activity Schema / Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Activity = mongoose.Schema({
  sender_id : {type: String, required: true },
  user_id : {type: String, required: true },
  product_id : {type: String, default : "" },
  type : {type: String, required: true },
  createdAt : {type: String, default : new Date()}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Activity', Activity);
```

Comment: Can you show us your schema for the activity table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`createdAt : {type: Date, default : new Date()}`
```

Type Date not string man

Comment: oh i see, so that mongoose was sorting it because it's string and not sorting it because it is a Date? any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: when you use String instead of Data sort will sort data as alphabetical order a b c... like this, because it's string

Comment: @BagusSantoso And because you used "type: String" mongoose will basically call `.toString()` on any data you supply before storing. Try `new Date().toString()` in any REPL and see why this is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically create the createdAt and updatedAt

```
var options={
      timestamps: true
 }

var Activity = mongoose.Schema({
  sender_id : {type: String, required: true },
  user_id : {type: String, required: true },
  product_id : {type: String, default : "" },
  type : {type: String, required: true }

},options);
```